# Want jquery to replace same <li> and all element insie ul

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want jquery to include `<li>` and all other tags inside `<ul class="visib-1"></ul>` to `<ul class="visib-2"></ul>` without writing `li`,a `href=""` tags again. Is there have any solution?Is it possible to capture all elements from one UL and transfer to other UL?

From:

```
<ul class="visib-1">

    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Properties</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Start Now</a></li>
</ul>
```

To:

```
<ul visib-1>
   ?
</ul>
```

Comment: It is really hard to understand what you are trying to do and are asking of us.

Comment: Copy or move? Not really clear

Comment: [read this](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and also this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_clone.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to move from one `<ul>` to another:

```
$('#first-ul-id li').appendTo('#second-ul-id');
```

If you want to copy use clone()

```
$('#first-ul-id li').clone().appendTo('#second-ul-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Check the code below:
This code will also copy the event handlers attached.

```js
var cloneOfOld = $('[data-status="old"]').clone(true);
cloneOfOld.attr('data-status','new');
var newUl = $('[data-status="new"]');
newUl.replaceWith(cloneOfOld);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul data-status="old"><li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Properties</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Start Now</a></li>
</ul>
<ul data-status="new">

</ul>
```